# Android Google Maps error

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-activity

In my app I want to open a `MapActivity` from a button click. But on the button click,its showing a class not found error.

Im posting my error log also,so that it will be easy to correct me...

```
06-11 17:16:53.854: WARN/dalvikvm(890): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-11 17:16:53.865: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(890): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-11 17:16:53.865: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(890): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.iqmobi.SampleMapPage
06-11 17:16:53.865: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(890):     at com.iqmobi.Login.onClick(Login.java:61)
06-11 17:16:53.865: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(890):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
06-11 17:16:53.865: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(890):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
06-11 17:16:53.865: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(890):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-11 17:16:53.865: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(890):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-11 17:16:53.865: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(890):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-11 17:16:53.865: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(890):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-11 17:16:53.865: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(890):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-11 17:16:53.865: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(890):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-11 17:16:53.865: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(890):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-11 17:16:53.865: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(890):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-11 17:16:53.865: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(890):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-11 17:16:53.874: WARN/ActivityManager(60):   Force finishing activity com.iqmobi/.Login
06-11 17:16:54.384: WARN/ActivityManager(60): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{4505c5d8 com.iqmobi/.Login}
```

The code which is moving to the MapActivity is

```
Intent successIntent=new Intent(Login.this,SampleMapPage.class);
startActivity(successIntent);
```

An additional information i checked,that,when i Toast instead of startActivity in my above code section,its working....Its something related to the button click,i think.....please help

Comment: did you add the activity to the manifest?

Comment: yes.......but i need to know,whether any additional attribute to be given to that activity?

Comment: Did you add <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> to your manifest?

Comment: maybe post the code for where you start the activity com.iqmobi.SampleMapPage and for the class itself

Comment: add <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> to your manifest and define your activity in the right package in the manifest

Comment: your problem is solved or not???

Comment: not solved..........i will post the reason if it is solved........

Comment: you should post some code, exact line where this error throws..if your map activity called??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` to your manifest and make sure you're using the Google API version of Android. Your manifest should look something like [the one in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470220/mapview-and-error).

Comment: What IDE are you using? Eclipse?

Comment: Right click on your project, and click on properties. Then Select Android from the list on the left side of the window. You should now see a list of project build targets. Make sure you've got one selected that says "Google APIs" not just Android X.X

Comment: if he is not select google api as a target device than he is not extends mapactivity instead of activity.

Answer (score 1):

Write Below Code line into your manifest file's `<application>` tag.

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```